# how to configure python local packages site?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils, easy-install

how can a Python version be forced to look at a particular local user site/user base for packages?
I tried setting the environment variable `PYTHONUSERBASE` but it is ignored. Typing this:

```
$ python -m site --user-base
```

gives no output, similarly for

```
$ python -m site --user-site
```

I am also not clear what the difference is between user base and user site. when python is invoked, it always looks in the system wide `site-packages`, like `/usr/lib/...` and not the directory I specified in `PYTHONUSERBASE`.

How can this be configured? Relevant doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html

Comment: Is the problem that you cannot find a package or that you are finding an undesirable version of a package?

Comment: merlin2011: the problem is that it uses the system wide location of the package, which is older than the one i have installed in my local directory. i want it to always look in `~/.local/` *first*, but it doesn't

Comment: Please link the relevant documentation in your question.

Comment: What exactly are you setting `PYTHONUSERBASE` to, and where are the user packages located?

Comment: @merlin2011: I set `PYTHONUSERBASE` to `~/.local/` and the packages are in `~/.local/lib/python...` the usual directory.

Comment: I think user site-packages is designed as an additional entry in the module search path, after the global site-packages; it’s not supposed to be inserted before it.  PEP 370 should contain all info.

Virtualenvs or buildout would be a way to make Python use a local version that’s newer than a globally installed version.